# updating excel file data using vba from mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, database-connection

Is it possible to have an excel sheet that gets updated from a mysql server using a specific query when ever it gets opened using VBA?

I am new to VBA and is it possible to monitor the data changes on the excel sheet while updating the sheet??

Thanks

Comment: Very hardly. It would probably be easiest to have a remote PHP script that generates a CSV file, and to download and open that

Comment: You need to set up data connection to the server. I have the same solution for Oracle DB, and it works pretty smoothly.

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks for the answer..but i want it to be from the excel file itself as will be easy for me to work easily by not opening nay other applications like browser..

Comment: @PeterL. can you please explain how ??

Comment: @Prem_Kumar_S no any other applications needed: as soon as query is set up, you just need to refresh it. That's it. Fro my case DB select is linked as source data for pivot table.

Comment: @PeterL. I am still not getting...Can you please explain it bit detailed.with few steps

Comment: @Prem_Kumar_S Start with these links: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3358411/Connecting-with-Oracle-Accessing-Oracle-via-Access-and-Excel.htm and http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/microsoft-excel/how-to-query-oracle-from-excel-2007/ + see the answer below. For oracle taht was a lot more complicated, mysql is going to be much easier, but the principle is just the same. Good luck!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23793/discussion-between-prem-kumar-s-and-peter-l)

Comment: @PeterL.hi this is help ful..but this creates a dsn and stored in my computer...but want this to run in many computers at my network..It does not work in other computers as the dsn is not available there... and it coul be be more easy if the data is fetcched using nay connection string !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `Data` > `Get External Data` toolbar to set up the MySQL data pull, you can then set the workbook to refresh upon opening - [Here's a link](http://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=1577) that shows the very basics.

As for tracking / moitoring changes, you'd have to be more detailed about how you'd like that to happen... As a general rule, it's not very easy to do.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: get external data works based on DSN connection... I want this to be done with a connection string as it will be easy to access any where in my network...

Comment: What about `Data` > `From Other Sources` > `Other\Advanced` > in connection tab `Use Connection String`